# .NET Core EF - DbUpdateConcurrencyException

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, .net-core

I have a .NET Core 6.0 application, using Oracle w/ Entity Framework and I'm encountering some sporadic issues with `DbUpdateConcurrencyException`(s). I am not sure why it's happening, and other posts on SO and elsewhere haven't seemed to resolve my situation. I read someone say to check database triggers to make sure they weren't erroring out and apparently was the source of someone's `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` (disabled my triggers and the error remained). Others mentioned this can happen when updating child objects (I commented out the logic which does inserts/updates to the child tables and the error still occurs).

In the code below, this function takes in a single item and saves it to the database if it's new. The calling method will commit the changes to the database after successfully going through the entire dataset to process, which is where the error occurs when `.SaveChanges()` is called. I appreciate anyone's insight.

```
    private void ProcessItem(Item item)
    {
        // Check to see if this is an existing Item first
        LorStgItem itemDb = _unitOfWork.ItemRepository.GetByID(item.Id) ?? new LorStgItem();

        bool newItem = string.IsNullOrEmpty(itemDb.ItemItemno);

        // Item header
        itemDb.ItemAction = item.Action;
        itemDb.ItemUserdef1 = item.UserDefined1;
        itemDb.ItemUserdef3 = item.UserDefined3;
        itemDb.ItemCompany = item.Company;
        itemDb.ItemDesc = item.Description;
        itemDb.ItemLotcontrolled = item.LotControlled;
        itemDb.ItemNetprice = item.NetPrice.ToString();

        if (newItem)
        {
            itemDb.ItemItemno = item.Id;

            this.AddNewObjectForLN(ItemTypes.Unknown, itemDb);

            _unitOfWork.ItemRepository.Insert(itemDb);
        }

        // ... 

    }
```